# Auth0 Custom database mongodb

Tags: mongodb, auth0

I'm trying to store users on my own `mongo` database not the default (auth0 server).

Below is the script:

```
function create (user, callback) {
    mongo('mongodb://admin:pass@localhost:27017/mydb', function (db) {
    var users = db.collection('subscribers');

    users.findOne({ email: user.email },
        function (err, withSameMail) {

            if (err) return callback(err);
            if (withSameMail) return callback(new Error('the user already exists'));

            user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, 10);

            users.insert(user, function (err, inserted) {  
                if (err) return callback(err);
                callback(null);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

This is the error I'm getting when I try to create a user:

```
[Error] Error: socket hang up
at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:200:15)
at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:285:23)
at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:437:9)
at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:392:17)
```

Comment: Which driver is this? What is `mongo`, just the result of `require('mongodb')`? If the node native driver then you need to call `.connect()` on [`MongoClient`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/MongoClient.html). You are also writing some pretty inefficient code here. Read up on ["upserts"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) which basically does in one database call what you are doing with two ( lookup/insert where not exists). Some general tutorials would likely be worthwhile as well.

Comment: Of course there is also the primary concept that your application should connect to a database "once", and not with every seperate function call. Database connections are very costly, and as such should be maintained over the lifecycle of your application, rather than connecting and disconnecting all of the time.

Answer (score 3):

Your mongodb is in **localhost** (see your connection string). The `create` script runs in Auth0 servers, so **localhost** (your machine) is not reachable.

Normally your instance would run on a server that is reachable from Auth0 (e.g. mongolabs, a server in AWS, etc). If you are testing, then you might want to check out [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

Blakes suggestion of caching the connection is a good one, but it is an optimization, not the reason it is not working.

Comment: That make sense, will try it, thanks for your answer.

Comment: even though we create a url exposing db using ngrok, how to specify a port? which is required by the auth0? how to handle this port?